Why does the Visual Studio debugger sometimes stop one byte after a REX instruction prefix?

Sometimes, when breaking into a program in the Visual Studio debugger, I see the following weird phenomenon:

The debugger appears to display the next instruction byte as starting after the instruction's REX prefix.
Not only is this confusing, but it also clearly throws off the debugger itself, as it finds itself unable to show a disassembly of the preceding instructions as a result.
Confusingly enough, however, the program appears to run fine when executing is continued.
Why does this occur? Is the debugger merely displaying the next instruction incorrectly, or does execution actually begin at that byte somehow?

Update
I encountered the same issue again:
  00007FF621A5B994 4D                   ?? ?????? 
> 00007FF621A5B995 8D 51 0A             lea         edx,[rcx+0Ah]  

The relevant registers were:
RIP = 00007FF621A5B995, RDX = 0000000014587354, R10 = 0000000010F96302

After single-step, the registers became:
RIP = 00007FF621A5B998, RDX = 0000000014587354, R10 = 0000000010F9630C

Strangely, this means the displayed instruction pointer is wrong, but the correct one is executed.

You're probably in the best position to investigate this: did xmm0 change after single-stepping, or xmm8? If xmm0 changed then apparently that instruction was really executed without its REX prefix. If xmm8 changed then the debugger is confused. I don't remember encountering this and I wouldn't know how to try to reproduce this other than deliberately jumping partway into the instruction but doing it intentionally would mean nothing.

@user555045: Yeah, the thing is this happens quite rarely; I haven't been able to reproduce it for the past > 50 times I tried breaking into the program. I've seen it happen maybe 10 times over the past several months. If I manage to repro I'll update the post...

Were you perhaps debugging a program where the running process was out of sync with debug info, like if you rebuilt from source while an old process was still running?  Was this compiler-generated, or hand-written assembly built by NASM, FASM, GAS, or whatever?  Bogus debug info from hand-written asm is possible and can make debuggers show weird things.

Also, look at RIP in the debugger, does it match the actual start of the instruction, or the position the disassembly shows?

@PeterCordes: See update.

You didn't answer any of the questions in my first comment.  But interesting that before the single-step, the debugger shows a RIP that doesn't match the point it actually single-steps from.  That makes me think it's probably not just bad debug info, although perhaps bad debug info is what exposes this bug in the debugger(?), but could still be something else.

@PeterCordes: Sorry, I somehow entirely missed your questions. But to answer them: no, the debug info isn't out of sync, and there's no assembly, it's just straightforward C++.
